# undefined even? method in ruby code

Tags: ruby

I am trying to write a program which accepts 20 numbers as input from the keyboard and then I need to get the count of even,odd,positive and negative numbers from the entered numbers.I have written the following code

```
puts "Enter 20 numbers"
numbers = Array.new
while numbers.length <= 20
numbers << gets.chomp
end
puts "You have entered 20 numbers"
h = Hash.new
h["even"] = numbers.select {|x| x.even? && x > 0}.count
h["odd"] = numbers.select {|x| x.odd? && x > 0}.count
h["positive"] = numbers.select {|x| x > 0}.count
h["negative"] = numbers.select {|x| x < 0}.count
puts h
```

However I know this is a bad code.Also it throws the following error

```
 rytest.rb:9:in `block in <main>': undefined method `even?' for 
"7":String   (NoMethodError)
 from rytest.rb:9:in `select'
 from rytest.rb:9:in `<main>'
```

I am not aware what I may be doing wrong as I am very new to ruby.Please help me to get a proper solution for this.

Comment: You're calling `even?` on strings. Convert string from the input to integers with `gets.chomp.to_i`.

Comment: Exactly as @SergioTulentsev says... `gets.chomp` gets you a string like "3" but that's a string, not an integer and `"3".even?` is undefined.  If you change it so that you convert to an integer before you add it to the array, then you're ok.  `gets.chomp.to_i`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Come on, you can do better.

Comment: @sawa: what do you mean? :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev `chomp`.

Comment: I am Sorry @SergioTulentsev .But I dont seem to get what you want to imply.

Comment: @MaheshMesta: what sawa meant is that in `gets.chomp.to_i`, `chomp` is redundant. `.to_i` will handle trailing linebreak correctly (by ignoring it). So it can be just `gets.to_i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three things wrong here

1. As others have commented, you're calling a method on a String that doesn't exist. "gets" means "get string", and Strings don't have a `even?` method
2. Your loop is pulling 21 entries, rather than 20 because of `<=`. Arrays are based at `0`, so `< 20` is what you want
3. [0 is even](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_zero), but your code skips it

Fixed code:

```
puts "Enter 20 numbers"
numbers = Array.new
while numbers.length < 20
    numbers << gets.chomp.to_i
end
puts "You have entered 20 numbers"
h = Hash.new
h["even"] = numbers.select {|x| x.even? && x >= 0}.count
h["odd"] = numbers.select {|x| x.odd? && x > 0}.count
h["positive"] = numbers.select {|x| x > 0}.count
h["negative"] = numbers.select {|x| x < 0}.count
puts h
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to call `even?` on Integer instances

```
"1".to_i.even?
```

Example:

```
numbers = ["1", "2", "3"]
numbers.map(&:to_i).select(&:even?).select { |i| i > 0 } # => [2]
```

Comment: What is the difference between your answer and comments?